# My grab tool (sculptor mode) won't move horizontally any more

Tags: modeling

[image]

My grab tool (sculptor mode) won't move horizontally any more, is there any settings that I accidentally changed?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation about your issue, don't just post, images, videos or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Have you tried to press and release the Ctrl key? Looks like it's snapping to the axis. I had 2 or 3 times the situation that Blender thought for some reason I was pressing the Ctrl key - which I was not. That changed the mouse wheel function. After a hit on the key it worked again normally.

Comment: pressing Ctrl key and releasing did not work.